# Import vCard on android

Tags: java, android, contacts, contactscontract, vcf-vcard

I need to import multiple vCard files in android contacts, android contacts already have the feature of importing vCard files, what i need to do is to pass an Array contains paths to each vCard file and make the contacts app in android import them for me without user interaction.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> android contacts already have the feature of importing vCard files

Different devices have different "contacts" apps. Not all will necessarily support importing vCard files.

> and make the contacts app in android import them for me without user interaction

That is not possible. Even for those contact apps that support vCards, the import process is done by activities and therefore involves user interaction.

You will need to parse the vCard file(s) yourself and use the `ContactsContract` `ContentProvider` to add the contacts.